# execute Azure DataFactory pipeline from different datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have 6 datafactories.
4 of them in the same region, 2 in a different region.
They are in different resourcegroups.

In one of them (let's call this one `adf-mgmt`) I created a pipeline (`sendmail`) that sends an email if an error occurs;
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5718/azure-data-factory-pipeline-email-notification--part-1/

Can I use the pipeline `sendmail` from the other datafactories or do I need to recreate that pipeline in each datafactory?

Comment: You can't directly reference assets in another data factory. Not a great option, but you could use the REST API to execute external pipelines. A better option would be to place your sendmail action in an Azure Function that could be executed from virtually anywhere.

Comment: I will  look into that. We are trying to use as little code as possible but sometimes that may simply be necessary.
The pipelines are now calling a logic app. I do not directly see the difference between using a logic app or a function but as said, I will look into that. Thanx.

Comment: A Logic App could also work since both can be exposed as a REST endpoint. I would still encourage you to investigate Function Apps. LAs are workflows, where as FAs are encapsulated components. LAs and ADF both know how to leverage FAs, so they are very useful tools when building workflows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible via the Azure Data Factory REST API. "Create Run" would be your point of interest. Refer the below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/create-run

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29897686)

Answer (score 0):

Can I use the pipeline sendmail from the other datafactories or do I need to recreate that pipeline in each datafactory?

No, we can't. Data Factory doesn't support execute the pipeline from different pipeline.

Others have post the request in [Data Factory feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/36641200-execute-pipeline-task-in-a-different-datafactory), you could continue to vote up it to make the product team know:
[image]

And thanks for the good suggestion provided by @Joel Cochran:

"you could use the REST API to execute external pipelines. A better option would be to place your sendmail action in an Azure Function that could be executed from virtually anywhere."

"A Logic App could also work since both can be exposed as a REST endpoint. I would still encourage you to investigate Function Apps. LAs are workflows, where as FAs are encapsulated components. LAs and ADF both know how to leverage FAs, so they are very useful tools when building workflows."

You could follow the suggestion, or recreate that pipeline in each Data factory if you still could not figure it out with Azure Function or Login App.